# script for jp@gc - WebDriver Sampler

Tags: javascript, webdriver, jmeter

I have to login a website by providing credentials using Jmeter - WebDriver Sampler in JMeter. And this is my script,

```
WWDS.browser.get('http://login.salesforce.com')
var pkg = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium)
var username = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id('username'))
username.sendKeys(['prakash93@salesforce.com'])
var password = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id('password'))
password.sendKeys(['*********'])
var Login = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.cssSelector('button.button-Login'))
button.click()
```

Every thing is fine except the login button (last 2 lines) . Can anyone help me for login-button's script.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see Login button on that page looks like this:

```
<input class="button r4 wide primary" type="submit" id="Login" name="Login" value="Log In">
```

I.e.: the element name is `input`, rather than `button`, and it doesn't have class named `button-Login`. So CSS selector `button.button-Login` is not going to work.

But good news is that button has an `id`, so you can change it to:

```
var Login = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id('Login'))
```